# Rails, never-ending CSS request (CSS not loading)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, request, assets

I have a problem with CSS in my rails application, my browser tries to get the css assets but it ends up in a never ending request for every asset. I have also precompiled the assets and the CSS file containing all CSS looks fine. (JS files work fine).

Here is the image:
[image: Browser loading CSS files]

I'll paste some files that I think are important:

My structure for assets is:

```
app/assets/
├── images
├── javascripts
│   ├── application.js
│   ├── metro_ui
│   │   └── metro.min.js
│   └── static_pages.js.coffee
└── stylesheets
    ├── application.css
    ├── metro_ui
    │   ├── iconFont.min.css
    │   ├── metro-bootstrap-responsive.min.css
    │   └── metro-bootstrap.min.css
    └── static_pages.css.scss
```

app/assets/application.css:

```
 /*
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HelpDeskApp</title>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'
#ruby-gemset=help_desk_app

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

group :development do
  gem 'mysql2', '0.3.16'
end

gem 'angularjs-rails', '1.2.21'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
# gem 'turbolinks', '2.2.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.1.3'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.1', require: false
end
```

config/application.rb:

```
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module HelpDeskApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try this in different browsers? did you try "rake assets:clobber" first and then running it again?
Is the path you saw on your browser console for .css files (I cant see the .css file's paths from your image) "/assets"?
I couldn't see the exact problem but only thing that I can think of was the gems. Did you try to uncomment "turbolinks" for example? it could brake your jQuery but worth to try for css files

Comment: what's in static_pages.css.scss file? I hope it doesn't have another: `*= require_tree .`?

Comment: @bkdir wow, sry, it seems that is working properly and it is a firefox bug or something similar, in all browsers the css works well, even in firefox, but firefox shows this never-ending loop when looking at the CSS requests.

Comment: @Surya There's nothing in static_pages.css.scss file.